# Safari Extension to Manage Tabs?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, tabs

I'm looking for a more efficient way to manage my tabs in Safari. Specifically something that allows me to move multiple tabs at once to a new window.

I often find myself following a link for a new subject/idea, then another, and so on and so on, until I find myself with a dozen tabs that should really be in their own window, but it's a pain to manually find and drag each one. I'd love to be able to do it in one fell swoop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does such a plug in exist for any browser? What is the UI interaction to select multiple tags? When I need to do this, I just start dragging tabs - the first one drops a new window behind the current window and then I cycle through the tabs that are open, dragging the few that need to move to the destination window. Also, when I have more than 10 to 15 tabs, that's usually a sign they I need to just bookmark, read, dismiss most of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Poor mans answer - I use XMarks and do any management I need in their web interface. However Safari is close to getting the boot on my mac since I can only see 13 open tabs.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately managing the actual links isn't much of an issue, it's once those links get opened in Safari and dealing with the resulting tabs.

Comment: I'm using glims now. It brings Safari closer to Chrome in my mind. However if my safari pain continues I may just jump to Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I have develop this open source Tab Manager for Safari, I hope its useful to you. All the comments are welcome .

https://github.com/morsamatias/UltraTabSaver

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool, which could do this.

But a somewhat less inconvenient way would be to safe all tabs as bookmarks. Move all bookmarks you like to have opened in another window to another bookmarks folder, right-click on the folders name and open all tabs simultaneously.

Comment: This isn't really the same as managing tabs, as all tabs' sessions will end during the move.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs Saver for Safari (https://apps.apple.com/in/app/tabs-saver-for-safari/id1440006971?mt=12) is a good one. This is not a free app (close to 3.5$).
But this works perfectly as a session saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it vey easily. Use top menu History -> Reopen Last Closed Tabs.