# Web browser or extension to move multiple tabs between windows in a single action

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, safari, web-browser

In Safari, I'd like to be able select multiple tabs at once, and move them all to an open or new window. Looking for extension (or magic Safari invocation) that can [do this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55982), I find **no** viable solutions.

Since Safari lacks this feature, is there any browser on OS X that does a better job of this, out of the box, or with an extension.

Comment: Hi, You should put a bounty on the other question rather than ask it again and making a duplication

Comment: I just tried to clarify why I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm asking for more information than the related question did. Moreover, the answers on the related question are non-answer answers, neither of which was ever accepted.

Comment: Just curious, typically how many tabs total across how many windows would you like to have running? Do you often need to move more than 5 tabs?

Comment: Often enough, yes. Good question. I might end up writing an extension myself, because given my workflow (possibly misguided, but it's mine), I want to do this kind of thing all the time.

Comment: Any developments on this?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

You might run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set w to window 1
    set namelist to name of tabs of window 1
    repeat with i from 1 to (count namelist)
        set item i of namelist to (i & " " & (item i of namelist)) as text
    end repeat
    set answer to choose from list namelist with multiple selections allowed
    if answer is false then return
    make new document
    repeat with i in (reverse of answer)
        move tab ((word 1 of i) as integer) of w to beginning of tabs of window 1
    end repeat
    delete tab -1 of window 1
end tell
```

This moves the current tab and all tabs right of it to a new window:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set l to tabs of window 1 where index ≥ (get index of current tab of window 1)
    make new document
    repeat with t in (reverse of l)
        move t to beginning of tabs of window 1
    end repeat
    delete tab -1 of window 1
end tell
```

Both scripts reload each tab though.

I normally just copy the URLs of tabs as text:

```
set text item delimiters to linefeed
tell application "Safari" to URL of tabs of window 1
set the clipboard to result as text
```

I can then for example copy part of the lines and run `open $(pbpaste)`.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome supports this out of the box. Shift-click to select multiple sequential tabs (or cmd-click to select one --- cmd+shift-click also works) and drag them to create a new window.

Only downside is that it doesn't seem to work in fullscreen mode. [This post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/y-9Xfy8w8Ws) mentions an extension "Keyboard Detach/Reattach Tab" that adds that functionality.